# How to use TOCropViewController library with imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

[TOCropViewController Library](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)
I'am using this library through cocoa pods. import is done fine. but I'm unable to understand that how can i use this library when user select an image through imageview and the crop screen will appear and user cropped the selected image and the cropped image will fit to imageView.
I have tried and google it. but failed to to do that.
can anyone help me out. using swift 3.0

Here is code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!)
{

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        if image != nil
        {
            let image: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sample-image") // Load an image
            let cropController:TOCropViewController = TOCropViewController(image: image)
            cropController.delegate=self
            self.present(cropController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in })
}


//        Cropper Delegate

func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didCropTo image: UIImage, with cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int)
{
    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}


func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController, didFinishCancelled cancelled: Bool)
{
    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in  }
}
```

updated code:

when i call this function on viewdidLoad the crop screen appears and works fine. but i dont want to crop image in load controller. i want to crop image after selection of photo from library when user clicks imageView and select photo from photo library.

```
func presentCropViewController()
    {
        let image: UIImage = imageView.image! // Load an image
        let cropViewController = TOCropViewController(image: image)
        cropViewController.delegate = self
        present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

## calling

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        presentCropViewController()

}
```

updated code imagepicker

```
class user_info: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,TOCropViewControllerDelegate
{


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController();



  func tapDetected()
    {
        let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Media", message: "Select Camera or Photo Library", preferredStyle:.actionSheet)
        let cameraAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: {(cameraAction) in


            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) == true {

                self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else
            {
                self.present(self.showAlert(Title: "Message", Message: "Camera is not available on this Device or accesibility has been revoked!"),animated: true, completion: nil)


            }

        })

        let libraryAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: {(libraryAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) == true
            {

                self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
                self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else
            {

                self.present(self.showAlert(Title: "Message", Message: "Photo Library is not available on this Device or accesibility has been revoked!"), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        let cancelAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive , handler: {(cancelActn) in


        })

        alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
        alertController.addAction(libraryAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: is TOCropViewController is presenting using this code ?

Comment: i didn't understand what you are asking.  But i want to open crop window when user select the photo from library. but the crop screen didn't appear.

Comment: @ivarun: also check updated code